# How to manage Auto Renewable subscription dynamically iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to create Auto-Renewable subscription in my app for different themes criteria and that product items i will get in response of api.Based on product item i need to set that in itunes connect means dynamically add product items for app on itunes connect.Is this possible? And If yes, then please guide me for that.

I am attaching my screenshot to get more idea about that.

Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can [use the application loader](https://applicaster.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202074588-Creating-mass-IAP-products-in-iTunes-Connect) to bulk upload IAPs.  IAPs still need to be approved by Apple before they are available

Comment: Thanks for help @Paulw11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll still need to know the product_ids of all the the products that you want to fetch first, you can't dynamically get all products directly from Apple.

You can set up an API to get a list of product_ids (that are already set up in App Store Connect), then make an [SKProduct fetch request](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html) to ket the SKProducts for those identifiers.